# How to display errors on a form_for with multiple resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an order form where I can add order items

```
<h2>Order: <%= @order.title %></h2>

<h3>Items</h3>
<%= render @order.items %>

<h4>Add an item:</h4>
<%= form_for([@order, @order.items.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :Item %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

I want to check if there are any errors when creating the item.

This is what I use on the order form:

```
<% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this order from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I don't know how to display errors when there is multiple resources in the form for.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before and ended up wanting to really customize the messages. In order to do it, I used a solution like this:

```
<% if @errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this order from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @errors.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This allows you to create an @errors object in your controller where you build array of messages. For example something like this:

```
@errors = []
@errors += @order.errors.map(&:full_messages)
@errors += @items.map(&:errors).map(&:full_messages).flatten
...
```

I hope this helps!